# Mysql how to add unique key by using a column and year from the date of other column

Tags: mysql

I have an application which have campaigns and for each campaign there are campaigns numbers, date_start, date_finish, etc.
The campaign numbers are generated by using `YEAR(date_start)` and campaign_number.
The campaign_number start from 1 every year e.g 
year = 2014, campaign_number = 1,2,3,4,5....; 
year = 2015, campaign_number = 1,2,3,4,5....;

Right now there is no restriction on creating duplicate campaign numbers like this:
year = 2015, campaign_number = 1,2,1,3,4,2,5....; 

I want something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `campaign` ADD UNIQUE `campaign_numbers`(`campaign_number`, YEAR(date_start));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you will need to have or should have two columns. One for campaign year and one for campaign number and the in the table structure make these together a unique index.

This I believe would make it easier to make new campaigns and give them a unique number.

```
SELECT campaign_number FROM campaigns WHERE campaign_year = 2015 ORDER BY campaign_number LIMIT 1
```

Then for your new campaign you add 1 to the result. If your app is super busy making new campaigns all the time you could have a clash. However, on your insert you could catch any possible Unique violation and try with a higher number.

Comment: i dont want to create a new column `campaign_year` while having a column that already have the year in it

Comment: I understand what you re saying, maybe I am missing something, but it seems to me that you are trying to put 2 properties or attributes of something into one table column. The year and the number. I know that making a shortcut in the DB seems like a good idea to save time. But almost always in the end it is not. Please share your solution later on so that I can fully understand what you re trying to do.